# csrf_exclude_uri in CI version 2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, csrf, csrf-protection

i have some problem using `csrf_protection`. i want to hit `example.com/test/index_post` from a form in `mysite.com/myform` using post method form but when i submit the form error page

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

showed. I'm using CI version 2. 
i already know some solution using `csrf_exclude_uri` but it didnt work in CI version 2. is there other solution similiar with `csrf_exclude_uri` in CI version 2?

Comment: Upgrade to CI3. Not that doing so would resolve this, but still. Anyway, when you're opening your form, are you using: echo form_open('test/index_post') or are you trying to redirect $_POST data from the myform controller? The csrf_exclude_uri doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: oke, i think so, i jumped on conclusion that i have to upgrade my CI. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

according to my research and Joe's answer, the only way is to upgrade CI 2 to CI 3,because CI 2 dont have that services